# Getting a number of a text(?) document downloaded from server

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I need help understanding how to convert `NSData` into a `Int`. I first downloaded the textFile from a server by doing this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "path to server")!
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!

print(data) //confirmed there is data
//output in console is <31343231 340a>
```

When I downloaded the file on my computer, the file looks like this:

[image: screenshot of file on computer]

I looked around for ways to convert `NSData` to `Int`, and came across a technique like this:

```
var src: Int = 0
data.getBytes(&src, length: sizeof(Int))
print("price: \(src)") //output was 11219279950897
```

Unfortunately 2929 != 11219279950897. I presume it's something to do with possible white space in the document. Would be grateful if I can get some advice on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? (Swift 1.2)

```
let data = ...

if let
    datastring = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding),
    num = (datastring as String).toInt() {
    print(num)
}
```

Hope this helps.